# Canvas Painting app not drawing (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw, paint

I'm trying to make a basic painting app using javascript. When, and only when, the mouse is pressed down should the mouse draw to the canvas. My issue seems to be with the variables lastX and lastY. These variables should be the mouse pointer's current coordinates but they pick up the coordinates when the mouse is clicked and not when the mouse moves. These variables should be dynamic as the mouse moves and thus paints.

I know if I set the lastX and lastY to integers then when I click on the canvas it draws a straight line to those coordinates. I must be missing something as I'm not getting any errors with the code when testing, just not working!

Could someone help explain where I've gone wrong?

```
var mycanvas= document.getElementById("canvas");
var Line = mycanvas.getContext("2d");

// Mouse Coordinates 
var x;
var y;

// Mousedown - Drawing
mycanvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){console.log("Draw");  

    x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    mousePressed = true;

    Draw(x, y, true)


            return false;                               
    });

// draw function    

function Draw()
{  

 Line.beginPath();
 Line.strokeStyle = "#000000";
 Line.lineWidth =10;
 Line.lineJoin = "round";
 Line.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
 Line.lineTo(x, y);
 Line.closePath();
 Line.stroke();

var lastY = y;
var lastX = x;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the **[mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove)** event instead of mousedown.

There are several other issues with your code though. You are calling Draw(x, y, true), but you defined Draw without any parameters. Also, you are declaring lastX and lastY as local variables at the bottom of Draw, but using them above where they are declared in Line.moveTo(lastX, lastY). You're also missing a semicolon after your call to Draw(x, y, true).